# Symfony2 - Call to a member function getPassword() on a non-object on login

Tags: php, symfony

I've implemented a simple standard login with symfony. The error only appears when I enter the right credentials and this is the full error:

> Error: Call to a member function getPassword() on a non-object in C:\BitNami\wamp\apache2\htdocs\Scouter\front\src\Scouter\UserBundle\Entity\User.php line 422

A screenshot of the Stack Trace can be found here: http://bit.ly/1lXQvtS

security.yml

```
encoders:
    Scouter\UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
        cost:      15

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    scouter_users:
        entity: { class: UserBundle:User }

firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /user/login_check
            login_path: /user/login
        logout:
            path:   /user/logout
            target: /
        anonymous: ~
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /
            domain:   ~
```

I have separated [user](https://github.com/hstandaert/scouter/blob/master/front/src/Scouter/UserBundle/Entity/User.php) and [member](https://github.com/hstandaert/scouter/blob/master/front/src/Scouter/UserBundle/Entity/Member.php) entities because of the fact that I want to implement oauth later. The password is stored in my member entity, username is stored in User entity.
[image: db-model]

```
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->getMember()->getPassword();
}

public function getSalt()
{
   return $this->getMember()->getPassword();
}
```

**UPDATE:** I have been debugging and dumping all possible variables inside symfony's core code. The error is caused by the fact that the user that is saved in the AbstractToken returns the member *ID* instead of the member *object*. I still don't have a clue why that is... so feel free to suggest possible solutions.

I had this working a some time ago. I don't know what went wrong. Anyone who has any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your authentication handler's code.

Comment: I do not have a custom authentication handler, I think. I'm using Symfony's standard user/authentication provider? If I'm wrong about this: where do I find this code?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add an "use Scouter\UserBundle\Entity\Member" and instantiate this in your constructor inside User class?

Comment: What is `member`? where is it populated? It's currently null, and that's the reason for the error.

Comment: I edited my question, Noy Gabay. In my user repository (which extends UserProviderInterface), when I dump the User entity in the refreshUser() method, the member is properly loaded.

Comment: Please post your mapping for User and Memeber entities

Comment: I added links to the github repository. You can view them there (otherwise my question will become too chaotic) Entire repo at: https://github.com/hstandaert/scouter

Comment: @HelenaStandaert i've never created an entity without primary key.. I couldn't find any primary key in your member entity...

Comment: @HelenaStandaert Can you apply small change in Members class to make the `$user` mapping as nullable=false (`@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id", nullable=false)`)? Also what if you use `$this->member->getPassword();` instead?

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote above, there is no unique primary key (usually id) in your Member entity (I don't know, may be I'm wrong, may you didn't upload the full version of your entity to github..). If you've forgotten to add, just add it, Doctrine uses it to get the reference to the object..

Comment: The primary key is mapped onto the user_id column... Or is this not possible, since it is also a one-to-one relation with the user table

Comment: @HelenaStandaert you need to add unique primary key to your Member entity, and specify it above `protected $member` in User entity. Because, by default Doctrine references to object by `id` (it's a popular name), if it've been called differently in your schema definition, then you need to specify it in mapping information. I've never used annotation mapping, here is a sample example how this is done in xml format: `<one-to-one field="aEntity" target-entity="Vendor\MyBundle\Entity\AEntity" inversed-by="bEntity"><join-column name="a_entity_id" referenced-column-name="id" /></one-to-one>`